# Regarding BGE (Blender Game Engine), is it possible to generate a single .exe file from multiple files linked together?

Tags: blender, blender-game-engine

Would any of you guys or gals know the answer, please?

I know one can generate a .exe (windows executable) file from a single blend file. My question is very simple: Can anyone generate a single .exe file from multiple blender files of a same project?

For instance, say I have a project folder with several subfolders and files from my project game. Each folder has specific elements like scenes, models, textures, etc. They are all linked together to form the final game. Now I want to generate a single .exe file for my game. Is this possible?

Or, rather, should I make an entire game inside a single .blend file? (It seems like a very unlikely arrangement, maybe even impossible, but I rather ask). Or maybe even create a master .blend file from where to link all data and when project is finished pack everything before generating the executable (.exe)?

Comment: This is why I suggest that people write their own engines. Sure it's time consuming, but given all the free open source engines it's super easy to build one from the ground up in just a few months. Not only is it 100% yours, but you can do whatever you want without being caught up on the limitations of someone else's engine.

Comment: You and I have very different definitions of "super easy", it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend appending all of your assets to one blend file, and export it as a standalone. Some blender games either crash or fail to load because the operating system prevented another blend file from being used.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the delayed answer, really, it's been so much time that I didn't expect the question to be answered anymore.